# Expand a variable containing a prefix that is a name of the directory containing all files by indicate the extension of files

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I have a directory `temp_sources` that contains Fortran `.f90` files.

I try to expand the wildcard `*.f90` to print, with the `temp_sources` directory as prefix, all the Fortran90 files.

To summarize, I would like to store in a variable :

```
temp_sources/file1.f90
temp_sources/file2.f90
temp_sources/file3.f90
...
temp_sources/file11.f90
```

I tried to do in a script that takes 2 arguments (the first for the directory, i.e `temp_sources` and the second for `*.90`)

```
dir1="$dir1"
# Adding a slash for directory if not present
[[ "$dir1" != */ ]] && dir1=$dir1"/"
# Try to expand the files *.f90
files=( "$dir1${@:2:$#-2}" )
# Try to print the list with directory name as prefix
echo "$files"
```

But in only prints (with last echo) : `temp_sources/*.f90`

It doesn't expand the list of `.f90` files into `temp_sources` directory as prefix.

I don't know how to get this list with this directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
files=( "$dir1"${@:2:$#-2} )
```

You want the shell to process the expansion of the `*`, so it should not be enclosed in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! just a last precision : why don't we use `$2` as second argument instead of `${@:2:$#-2}` ? maybe since I am obliged to quote the `*.f90`by taking `$2`, i.e put `'*.f90'` in command line ?

Comment: I don't know, I just mimmicked your command, but I don't know why did you used that complicated syntax. That will handle more than an argument, and it will probably fail in this command, just because it won't probably do what you expect. My approach to the problem would be different: two arguments, the folder and the extension. No stars in the arguments, and the, in the code, add your star accordingly: `files=( "$1"/*"$2" )`